# How to recover WhatsApp media after getting a new phone?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

I bought an iPhone 8 to replace my iPhone 6. I was able to migrate absolutely everything via the "Quick Start" functionality.

However, when I opened WhatsApp on my new phone, all the media sent via WhatsApp was gone. For example, I had a collection of "starred" GIFs that now is only displayed as a bunch of items without an image, and when I try to select one of them I get a "This item could not be selected. please choose a different item" error message.

How can I recover the WhatsApp media (including the GIFs) from my previous phone? I still have the iPhone 6 with all its data.

Thank you.

Comment: In Whatsapp, you can make a backup of all your chats and media, open Whatsapp and go to Settings > Chats > Backup

Answer (score 3):

Backup your Whatsapp data in your old iPhone 6 to iCloud. Once it's successful, restore the backup data on your new iPhone 8.

Hope this helps.

I don't think there is any other way to restore it.

Comment: This is the only way without doing a full backup and restore. Consider going to Settings > Chats > Chat Backup and start the backup process. Once completed, try to recover your new iPhone with the same iCloud account. When installing WhatsApp with the same account (current mobile number when moved) the system should recover automatically.